# Updating DB(MySQL) based on varchar value

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a DB with table and some fields. The fields are "test" and "update".

When I try to update the field "update"(with letters/numbers etc) by specific "test"(only numbers) value, there's no problems what so ever. For example:

updating "`update`" for "`whatever235`" where "`test`" is equal to "`123452`" will update it successfully with no problems.

But, if I try to update the "update" based "test" value with letters(abc...) I get fail. For example:

updating "update" for "whatever235" where "test" is equal to "qwerty" will throw an error to me.

My `"test"` structure is `varchar(256)` `utf8_unicode_ci.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you specify what error is throwing..?

Comment: The one I specify to throw ( `throw new Exception()` )

Comment: Or perhaps there's a way to see a more detail error?

Comment: try to see that error by function mysql_error(); in OR statement of your query.

Comment: It's deprecated... and I'm getting hardtime with the `PDOStatement::errorInfo` :/